# A manga about man having hand replaced by a gun

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read a manga years ago about a man who replaced one of his arm with a gun.

In his adventure, he met a spaceship having strange lifeforms - they are living swords.

I cannot recall that manga name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is enough of a trope that it [has it's own page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArmCannon).  You might check there to see if you find anything that fits.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be *[Space Adventure Cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_(manga))*?

> Set in the far future, the series tells the story of Cobra, who lives an adventurous life until his enemies begin to hunt him down. Cobra surgically alters his face and erases his own memory to hide from his foes and have a normal life. Eventually, he regains his memories and reunites with his former partner Lady Armaroid. Terasawa devised it as a mix of Spaghetti Western and samurai stories, and aspects of films, varying from James Bond to Disney.

....

> Cobra (コブラ, Kobura) is the main protagonist and eponymous character of the series. Cobra's signature weapon is the Psychogun, an energy cannon hidden in his left forearm and controlled by his will (hence the name of the gun), which can burn through almost any material and take down any opponent. He also carries a Python 77 Magnum revolver as a backup weapon, less powerful but still useful against some enemies resistant to the Psychogun such as Crystal Bowie. He also possesses superhuman strength and stamina.

[Episode 21 of the anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Cobra_episodes#Episode_list), "The Two Sword Kings", apparently based off of the manga, has Cobra meeting the Swordians.

> Cobra and Lady create a distraction for the Swordians in the Sand Sea so that the settlers can escape. However Swordians' secret base, the Sand Rook which rises out of the sand and they are captured. Cobra escapes from his cell, finds a hidden passageway and discovers the chained Swordian King Jeek. He explains that the Swordians are actually swords, and the armoured figures who wield them are their puppets. They used to feed on the energy of animals, but now Babel is now using humans instead. Cobra frees King Jeek, and dressed in his armour, challenges Babel to a duel. During the fight, Babel is exposed to be using a robot to amplify his psychic powers. Cobra uses his own senses to defeat him, restoring King Jeek to the throne and allowing the settlers to remain without fear.

Found by browsing anime entries on the TV Tropes [Arm Cannon](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArmCannon) page.